# Android 13 sdcard/DCIM/Camera shows empty

Tags: javascript, android, google-apps-script

I have published Apps which get photos from DCIM/Camera and shows them as symbols. Since updating my tablet from Android 12 to 13 this no longer works. This is my code

```
    public int readPhotoFolder(String dirFolder){
    int limit;
    Log.i(TAG,"dirFolder= "+ dirFolder);
    File fdcim = new File(dirFolder + "DCIM");
    File fcamera = new File(dirFolder + "DCIM/Camera/");
    Log.i(TAG,"fdcim= "+fdcim);
    if(!fdcim.isDirectory()){
        return 0;
    }
    if(fdcim.isDirectory()) {
        Log.i(TAG,"fcamera= "+fcamera);
        if(!fcamera.isDirectory()){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //String cameraPath = dirFolder.toString()+"DCIM/Camera";
    File f = new File(String.valueOf(fcamera));
    Log.i(TAG,"f= "+f);
    File file[] = f.listFiles();
    limit = file.length;
    Log.i(TAG,"limit= "+limit);
    for (int i=0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        photoNames.add(dirFolder+"DCIM/Camera/"+file[i].getName());
    }
    return (limit);
}
```

Logging shows I am accessing the correct address but when I try to listfiles it says the folder is empty when I can see 5 photos on the PC and using the Explorer App.
I have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_MEDIA_IMAGES in Manifest. What has changed?

Comment: If you also requested READ_MEDIA_IMAGES at runtime then your code should work.

Comment: `File f = new File(String.valueOf(fcamera));` Dont create a new File instance if you have already the right one: `File fcamera`.

Comment: Also use fcamera.exists() before you try to list.

Comment: `readPhotoFolder(String dirFolder)` We cannot see which value you use for dirFolder. Probably the wrong one. Update your code please to make that clear.

Comment: dirFolder is set to various options where photos could be including System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") +"/"; Logging shows f= /sdcard/DCIM/Camera

Comment: What I have just found is that File file[] = f.listFiles(); ONLY finds Directories not files.  Any ideas how to get files?

Comment: If on Android 13 and READ_MEDIA_FILES your app should be able to list all image files in public DCIM directory and sub directories.

Comment: Can now access photos. I did it by setting Camera and photos permissions in Settings/"my app"/Permissions on my tablet. So how do I set this in code?

Comment: Which permission are you talking about? And did you read my first comment?

Comment: I did add READ_MEDIA_IMAGES to Manifest. It was only after setting the permissions on my tablet that my App could access DCIM/Camera. This seems to be only on Android 13

Comment: DID YOU READ MY FIRST COMMENT?

Comment: blackapps Thanks for your assistance. I think I have finally worked it out. Previously I had been checking the DCIM/Camera folder for photos before starting Gallery which prompts you to allow access to photos. By removing the initial check and going straight to Gallery it works. So Android 13 doesn't allow access to Camera folder prior to the prompt. Hope this makes sense.